# ngb-Carousel change next and prev indicators to very thin?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

How to change ngb-Carousel  next and prev indicators to very thin? i am using the "webkit-text-stroke 4px #fff" to make thinner arrows when background is white but if background is image then this web stroke is not working as expected[i need to do like this](https://www.canadaqbank.com/)

[i added image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4wFi.png)

Comment: is the image you added to your post yours or the result you want?

Comment: result i want sir